# access with js to thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, spring, thymeleaf

I work with thymeleaf and Spring and have to insert records into a JS table to create a Gantt chart. My problem is, that I have no idea how to insert the data with thymeleaf in the JS table.

Spring-Controller (Java)

```
@GetMapping("/{auftragID}")
public ModelAndView generateGanttDiagramm(@PathVariable int auftragID)
{
   ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
   model.setViewName("diagramm/gantt");
   List<Slots> list = getList();
   model.addObject("slots", list);
   return model;
}
```

JS-Code

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

data.addRows([
   ['Make Homework, 'Make Homework,, 'Work', new Date(2018, 2, 6), new Date(2018, 2, 07), null, 100, null],
   ['Play Football', 'Play Football', 'Sport', new Date(2018, 2, 6), new Date(2018, 2, 9), null, 100, null],
   ['Clean Car', 'Clean Car', 'Car', new Date(2018, 2, 8), new Date(2018, 2, 10), null, 100, null],
]);
```

Can you help me, please.